# Loading OpenStreetMap data to a custom PostgreSQL schema via osm2pgsql

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

What is the procedure to load OSM to a different schema than public?

The osm2pgsql [documentation](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/docs/usage.md) mention the parameter `--prefix` for specifying the tables prefix (planet_osm by default) but does not mention the schema name.
Running `osm2pgsql -h -v` to list all available commands, it seems there is no parameter for specifying the schema.

How can I load OSM data to a custom schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since osm2pgsql version 1.4, you can specify a destination schema with option `--output-pgsql-schema` when you use default behaviour (implicit `-O pgsql` default option). So, it would look like the following

```
osm2pgsql --create \
    -H localhost -U postgres -P 5432 -d mydb \
    --slim --drop \
    --output-pgsql-schema=myschema \
    extract.osm.pbf
```

If you use Flex output using `-O flex`, you may look at this sample https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/flex-config/with-schema.lua#L12 to specify the output schema destination in the lua file.

Beware as you need to create the destination schema before specifying it.

Answer (score 5):

`osm2pgsql` creates the tables and indexes in the user default schema, i.e. the first one found in its search path, which is usually `public`. By changing this setting, in PostgreSql, one can load the data to a custom schema. It is important to keep the `public` schema in the path, as it is required for getting the `hstore` type.

```
--Create the new user
CREATE USER osm_loader WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '*****';
--create the schema
CREATE SCHEMA osm AUTHORIZATION osm_loader;
--Change the search_path. 
ALTER ROLE osm_loader SET search_path TO osm, public;
```

and you can then launch the osm2pgsql tool with the new user

```
osm2pgsql.exe data.osm.pbf -U osm_loader [... other parameters as needed]
```

Alternatively, you could change the search path of the user you are currently using. Make sure to change it back once the data is loaded.

Comment: It is a pity that this is so complicated. Why is it not possible to choose the target schema as parameter?

Comment: Added an updated answer due to both osm2pgsql 1.4 change and additional flex support

Answer (score 1):

Here's some Python code I'm using to import osm data to a certain schema -

```py
# params
dbname = 'mydb'
username = 'postgres'
schema = 'austin'
osmfile = 'austin.osm'
style = 'all.style'

# change search path to new schema
# osm2pgsql will import the osm data to the first schema in the search path
sql = f"CREATE SCHEMA {metro}; ALTER ROLE {username} SET search_path TO {metro},public;"
cmd = f'psql --dbname {dbname} --command "{sql}"' # windows needs double quotes around sql
print(cmd)
os.system(cmd)

# import osm data
# uses slim mode - see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql#Slim_mode
cmd = f"osm2pgsql --create --latlong --slim --hstore --style {style} --database {dbname} --username {username} {osmfile}"
print(cmd)
os.system(cmd)

# change search path back to public schema
sql = f"ALTER ROLE {username} SET search_path TO public;"
cmd = f'psql --dbname {dbname} --command "{sql}"'
print(cmd)
os.system(cmd)
```